# detecting parallel port?

Tags: portscan

I'm trying to setup a pc with linux to control a hardware connected to the parallel port (parallel port on mainboard, not on PCI)

The original old PC is still working , I'm trying to setup a new one for more future safety.

The problem is that the linux PC, when hoocked up to the hardware, does not detect the parallel port.

[HERE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) I found a debugging for printers on parallel port. (my hardware is not a printer). I entered these commands, but as a linux newbie I do not know what to do with the answers.
Here's what I entered and the feedback:

```
root@linuxPC:~# lsmod ¦ grep lp
lp               7028  0
parport         32635  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
drm_kms_helper  29361  1 i915
drm            164468  3 i915,drm_kms_helper

root@linuxPC:~# lsmod ¦ grep ppdev
ppdev            5259  0
parport         32635  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp

root@linuxPC:~# lsmod ¦ grep parport_pc
parport_pc      26250  1
parport         32635  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp

root@linuxPC:~# dmesg ¦ grep par
[    0,000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.388860] pci 0000:00:le.0: transparent bridge
[    0.400572] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 Mhz counter
[    0.877097]  sda: unknown partition table
[   10.926746] parport_pc 00:09: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   10.926816] parport0:PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP]
[   10.949768] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   11.017043] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).

root@linuxPC:~# ls -l /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe* 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2016-08-19 15:00 /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport0/autoprobe
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2016-08-19 15:00 /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport0/autoprobe0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2016-08-19 15:00 /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport0/autoprobe1
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2016-08-19 15:00 /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport0/autoprobe2
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2016-08-19 15:00 /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport0/autoprobe3

root@linuxPC:~#  sudo cat /proc/sys/dev/parport/parport*/autoprobe*

root@linuxPC:~#  lpinfo -v
direct scsi
serial serial:dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
serial serial:dev/ttyS1?baud=115200 
network ipp
network http
network socket
direct parallel:/dev/lp0
network smb
network lpd

root@linuxPC:~#
```

On the internet I found that my hardware has to be on io-address 0x378 and

```
root@linux:~# cat /proc/ioports ¦ grep par
0378-037a : parport0
```

The manual of the software says that BIOS settings must be:
Parallel Port: SPP recommended
ACPI Suspend type - S1
HPET Support - Enabled
Limit CPUID MaxVal - Disable
C1E Function - Disable
EIST Function - Disable

I hope this makes more sense to you, I'do not understand anything.
Thanks for your help
jumperger

Answer (score 1):

You have an SPP port on the correct address.

> [   10.926816] parport0:PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP]

Your linux installation is seeing the port and loading the appropriate modules.
[your lsmod results show lp, ppdev, and parport_pc all using parport]

Since your hardware isn't a printer, the software may want to use its own driver or it may be a driver bitbanging the port.  Since the port address is specified in the software manual, this is probably the case.  You most likely need to blacklist some or all of the modules [lp, ppdev, parport_pc, and parport.]

It would help to know what hardware/software you are attempting to use.  You should also consider doing the lsmod commands on the working old PC to see what modules are loaded there.